# How to SUM a column of values in Sheet A IF a different column of values IS EQUAL TO a column of values in Sheet B

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am working with Google Sheets/Excel.
In Sheet A, I have the names of customers who have purchased various items, along with the cost of those items.

**Sheet A**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | Toothbrush | $1.00 |
| Customer B | Pencil | $2.00 |
| Customer C | Tent | $5.00 |
| Customer C | Juice | $4.00 |

In Sheet B, I want to calculate the total amount of money spent by each customer, by referencing their name from Sheet A.

**Sheet B**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Customer A | $1.00 |
| Customer B | $2.00 |
| Customer C | $9.00 |

This is what I have tried so far. I put these formulas into Sheet B, Column B:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"='Sheet A'!A:A")

=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet A'!C:C,COUNTIF(A:A,"='Sheet A'!A:A))"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `google-sheet` you can use `QUERY()` function like

```
=QUERY(A1:C4,"Select A, Sum(C) Group By A Label A 'Customer', Sum(C) 'Sum'")
```

If you want result in `Sheet2` then use below

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C4,"Select A, Sum(C) Group By A Label A 'Customer', Sum(C) 'Sum'")
```

[image]

In `Excel-365` I use below formulas

```
E2=UNIQUE(A1:A4)
F2=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$4,$A$1:$A$4,E2#)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun. What if instead of only selecting cells A1:C4, I want to select the entire columns?

Comment: Simply change `A1:A4` to `A:C` or `A2:C` in `google-sheet`.